# flutter - compare dates on showDateRangePicker

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a filter method in my app, and to filter Dates, I'm using `showDateRangePicker()`. What I need to do is limit the number of days the user selects. He can select any day, as long as the difference in days is not greater than 30. How can I show the user that he has selected more than 30 days in the calendar, without him needing to close it?

[image]

Here you have more than 30 days selected, and only when you close the calendar, the alert appears to the user.

Here my showDateRangePicker method:

```
showDateRangePicker(
              context: context,
              firstDate: firstDate,
              lastDate: lastDate,
              builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                return Theme(
                  data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
                    primaryColor: Colors.pink,
                    accentColor: Colors.white,
                    colorScheme:
                        ColorScheme.light(primary: const Color(0xFFF48fb1)),
                    buttonTheme:
                        ButtonThemeData(textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary),
                  ),
                  child: child,
                );
              },
            ).then(
              (_picked) {
                picked.add(_picked.end);
                picked.add(_picked.start);
               },
            );
```

Comment: Can you share the code you use to show the daterangepicker and the alert? That'd probably help figure out a solution

Comment: I just added my code, I forgot lol.

Comment: Hmm, I would normally expect there to be some sort of validation like there is for regular `TextFormField`s, but it doesn't seem to be an option here... Let's hope there is a simple solution I'm missing

Comment: I use two date pickers to handle this situation.